# How to give proxy Authentication (College Proxy) to window machine (Terminal or Powershell ) to download anything using proxy?

Tags: powershell, authentication, terminal, proxy, window

**WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/ipdp/**

This is a warning massage I'm getting from powershell. How to give **proxy Authentication** to **powershell** and **Terminal**?

I am a computer Science student, use College Proxy to download any thing from internet. While I can download files through web browser, but I encounter issues when attempting to download files using terminal and powershell. How can I bypass Proxy Authentication for these tools?

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/http-error-407/#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9C407%20Proxy%20Authentication%20Required%E2%80%9D%20error%20occurs%20when%20the%20server,unable%20to%20authenticate%20the%20client.